# Regex to find multiple words that don't match (Negative words matching)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to allow only a specific word per time per string, but exists multiple valid words.

Using the below regex i am not getting the expected result:

```
preg_replace('/\b^(true|false|TRUE|FALSE)\b/', '', 'false'); // Returns an empty string, but i expect 'false'

preg_replace('/\b^(true|false|TRUE|FALSE)\b/', '', 'test') // Returns 'test', but i expect an empty string
```

Someone knows what's wrong?

**EDIT 1**

An example for a long input:

```
preg_replace('/\b^(true|false|TRUE|FALSE)\b/', '', 'This regex allow only boolean, such as true, false, TRUE and FALSE');
```

It prints:

```
// This regex allow only boolean, such true, false, TRUE and FALSE
```

But i expect an empty string, because only a sigle word should be a valid match

Comment: Could you show the desired result for a larger string? What about all that is not a word?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I made just now, please see it

Comment: You have 4 matching words in `'This regex allow only boolean, such as true, false, TRUE and FALSE'` then how can final output be an empty string? Can you try to clarify your requirement better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't need a regex, you can use `in_array`:

```
$arr = array('true', 'false', 'TRUE', 'FALSE');

$result = (in_array($str, $arr, true)) ? $str : '';
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! I am going to use it because is simple and easy to change.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong for what you're trying to do. You will need negative lookahead.

Try this code:

```
$re = '/\b(?!(?:true|false|TRUE|FALSE))\w+\b/'; 
$str = 'I need true to allow only false specific FALSE words in a TRUE string'; 

$repl = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
//=>   true    false  FALSE    TRUE
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hN3wX9)

Comment: Nice, thanks! How can i change to allow only a single word as valid match? I made an edit, please see it.

Comment: Yes I just asked a question in comments above as I am unclear on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I well understand your needs, but is that OK for you:

```
if (preg_match('/^(true|false|TRUE|FALSE)$/', $string, $match)) {
    echo "Found : ",$m[1],"\n";
} else {
    echo "Not found\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

(?=.)(true|false|TRUE|FALSE|\s*)(?!.)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8oX3ibPh6h4SQjKq)

```
$regex = '/(?=.)(true|false|TRUE|FALSE|\\s{0,})(?!.)/';
$testString = ''; // Fill this in
preg_match($regex, $testString, $matches);
// the $matches variable contains the list of matches
```

Comment: I will follow the @CasimiretHippolyte suggestion and use a simple `in_array()`, it will be easier to understand and maintain. But thanks for you help!

Comment: I recommend that approach too.  I just did this for fun :)